# Unable to install new virtual keyboard language

Tags: 7.0-nougat, languages, samsung-galaxy-s7

After I recently reset my Samsung Galaxy S7 to factory defaults, several perplexing issues have occurred. Most notably, when I try to add an additional language to my Samsung virtual keyboard, the progress bar remains at 0%. This only occurs for certain languages such as Chinese and Safe Mode does not resolve this. How do I resolve this issue?

My path is: 
Settings->General Management->Language and Input->Virtual Keyboard->Samsung keyboard->Languages and types->Add input languages.

Device: Samsung Galaxy S7 (Latest update), Developer Options enabled (However no changes were made) , 60 GB SD card and No Services Installed in Accessibility.

Side note: After the factory reset, when the device started up, there was a screen which asked for a password, followed by a padlock icon in a spinning circle. This did not occur before the reset. Does this have anything to do with the issue I am experiencing? ( After doing research, this padlock screen indicates that my phone has encryption protection, however I did not enable this option in settings and I am unable to find it in settings.)

Attempted solutions: Clearing app data.

Comment: If the answer to this will be too long, is there a more appropriate website to ask this question?

Comment: See if clearing keyboard data helps. Settings>application manager>in the three dots menu, select 'show system apps'>scroll to Samsung keyboard>storage>clear data

Comment: I just tried it. Issue remains.